# PS to EPS preserving bounding box

Tags: graphics, conversion, eps, svg, ps

I have an SVG file and would like to turn that into EPS for embedding into a latex file to be eventually used by dvips. I can use `rsvg-convert` to turn my SVG into PS. I then can use `ps2eps` to turn that into EPS. But `ps2eps` does adjust the bounding box, which means that the resulting EPS will not show the whitespace as instructed by the SVG file.

Is there a way to prevent this, i.e. to convert PS to EPS while maintaining the `BoundingBox` of the original PS file?

The best I could come up with so far is this:

```sh
rsvg-convert -f ps -d 600 -p 600 --background-color=white -o foo.ps foo.svg
ps2eps -f -H foo.ps
sed -i~ "s/^%%BoundingBox:.*/`grep ^%%BoundingBox: foo.ps`/" foo.eps
```

But I consider this approach pretty hackish.

Comment: Why don't you use the PS produced by `rsvg-convert` as is? Or just say `mv foo.ps foo.eps` if you want. Be aware that `rsvg-convert` produces raster images from its input.

Comment: @AlexG: The PS generated by rsvg-convert isn't denoted as EPS, according to the file header. I'm not sure if it is safe to embed, if it cleans up the stack and state properly. It might be, though. Good idea, will try that. I'm pretty sure that the generated file is a vector graphic. I zoomed in very far, it still looks smooth, and the file is pretty small. The code too looks like reasonable vector operations.

Comment: @AlexG: I tried directly embedding the PS into my latex file, and see no ill effects. Would you please post that solution as an answer?

Comment: As for rasterization, I was only reproducing what the man page tells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of embedding with `latex`+`dvips`, a one-page Postscript file with a `%%BoundingBox` entry can be safely regarded as encapsulated Postscript and doesn't require further processing. Thus, the output of `rsvg-convert` can be used directly.

Comment: [The spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) includes more requirements for an EPS file, in particular it must not use restricted commands (2.4), must clean up after itself (2.5 and 2.6), must contain a file type comment mentioning `EPSF` (2.1), and so on. That last condition is definitely not satisfied in my case, but apparently latex+dvips can cope with that well enough.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for the information. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @AlexG, could you please add more details for a newbie in latex? I want to turn a .ps file into a .eps, so that I can modify it using psfrag in latex. Or maybe it is better to start from a different format, e.g. .pdf or .svg?